# Mongodb not starting on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb, installation, ubuntu-14.04, database

I am trying to install and start mongodb locally:

I go through these steps (as shown in history):

```
1819  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv       7F0CEB10
1820  echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
1821  sudo apt-get update
1822  sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
1823  sudo service mongod start
```

But I get the following error log in /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

```
2016-01-05T22:51:21.869+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting :   pid=5394 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-172-31-45-129
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version:    OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-01-05T22:51:21.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" } }
2016-01-05T22:51:21.895+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2016-01-05T22:51:21.895+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2016-01-05T22:51:21.895+0000 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I previously had a mongodb installed which worked fine but stopped me from connecting to it after some changes I made to other services that were using mongodb. So I tried to remove that instance of mongodb and tried reinstalling, after which I am facing this issue.

I also try to look for the file: `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` but it does not exist on my system.

Comment: I know you say you can't find the `.sock` file, but I have to run `sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` each time before starting mongodb, maybe try this?

Comment: I removed that file but then faced an issue with insufficient space. I'm editing my question altogether

Comment: I had that issue too - had to change the path of where the data is stored in the conf file. Something similar to [this blog post](https://rohan-paul.github.io/mongodb_in_ubuntu/2015/09/03/How_to_Install_MongoDB_Iin_Ubuntu-15.04.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after installing MongoDB the same way, also got the error message 'Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock...'.

After doing a bit more digging I realised that the installation hadn't created the path `/data/db`, so here's what I did:

1. create the full path (the flag `-p` creates parent folders if they don't exist)

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /data/db
   ```
2. recursively change ownership of the folder `/data/db` to mongodb

   ```
   sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db
   ```

**edit**: if you're planning on running different instances of mongodb from different project folders, you, and not mongodb, should be the owner of the contents of `/data/db`, otherwise it will give you an error of the type `exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock`

3. Remove the temporary socket file

   ```
   sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
   ```
4. Initialise the mongod service

   ```
   sudo service mongod start
   ```

After this it was running smoothly in my system. I could start it or stop it and it would not give me any more errors.

Hope this helps :)